# Audio Ducking Permanently Reversed on Android 11

Tags: audio

One time, I was using the app WhatsApp while listening to music using Samsung Music app. Whenever I sent an outgoing message, it would play a short sound, which briefly **reduced** the media volume for the music, then it would return back to normal.

However, something weird happened, and the media volume was reduced by default. Whenever I sent an outgoing message, it would briefly **increase** before reducing it again to the default low. This now means the maximum volume is reduced.

The current behavior is such that when I'm listening to music, the maximum volume is low but when I receive a notification, the volume goes up briefly while the notification tone plays, then gets reduced when the notification tone is over.

The phone is Samsung A10s, running on Android 11.

I have tried restarting the phone, clearing data for the settings app and also the option to "Reset all settings." None have worked. How can I correct this issue without performing a factory reset?

Comment: Try turning do not disturb on and off again

Comment: Seems not to be working @Gantendo